# how to rename a name in excel with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I change the reference of a name, which refers to a set of cells, with Apache poi? I have already looked at the API and found a few functions such as `getNameName()`, I am unsure whether or not I have to use that or how I am supposed to use it.

Suppose I have a name "Names of students" that refers to cells $A$2:$A$10, I want to change in java this name to refer to cells $A$2:$A$20. Does anyone know how to do this?

edit: I looked at the documentation and tried to come up with a sample code but even this doesn't work.

code:

```
 InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Name name;
        name = wb.createName();
        name = name.getNameName("NameOFStudents");
        name.setRefersToFormula("=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$20");
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("test2..xlsx");
        wb.write(fileout);
        fileout.close();
```

Comment: Could you please share your code with us? You should provide [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EmreSavcı  I have never worked with apache poi before so I'm unsure of which functions to use or how to design the logic of the program. i haven't written any code for this specific problem. im really sorry if that is causing an issue.

Comment: So you should take a look documentation and examples for it. And also read [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @EmreSavcı i looked at the documentation tried to come up with a code about how it is that i wanna do it. but using the .getNameName doesnt seem to work and i do not know why. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i finally figured out how to do it. you use the workbook variable with the function `.getName()` to get the name that you require and assign it to a Name variable and then use `.setRefersToFormula()` to change the reference

code:

```
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Name name;
        name = wb.getName("NameOFStudents");
        name.setRefersToFormula("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$20");
        FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("test2..xlsx");
        wb.write(fileout);
        fileout.close();
```